# websocket + php + nginx - super simple

Tags: php, nginx, websocket

I'm trying to set up super simple websocket on PHP + nginx

## nginx

```
server {
    listen 8443 ssl;
    server_name  websocket.example.com;

    root  /var/www/public/websocket;

    ssl_certificate  /var/ini/ssl/public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /var/ini/ssl/private.key;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_websocket.log warn;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout  86400;
    }
}
```

## client

```
var host = 'wss://websocket.dyntest.dk:8443';
var socket = new WebSocket(host);
socket.onmessage = function(e){
    document.getElementById('ws_test').innerHTML = e.data;
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

## server

```
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 9000;
// Create WebSocket.
$server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($server, $address, $port);
socket_listen($server);
$client = socket_accept($server);
// Send WebSocket handshake headers.
$request = socket_read($client, 5000);
preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n#', $request, $matches);
$key = base64_encode(pack(
    'H*',
    sha1($matches[1] . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')
));
$headers = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
$headers .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
$headers .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key\r\n\r\n";
socket_write($client, $headers, strlen($headers));
// Send messages into WebSocket in a loop.
while (true){
    sleep(1);
    $content = 'Now: ' . time();
    $response = chr(129) . chr(strlen($content)) . $content;
    socket_write($client, $response);
}
```

## start websocket server

```
php -q public/websocket/index.php
```

## error

In the browser: `wss://websocket.example.com:8443/`

> ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? Is that error written in the shell, in the browser, somewhere in a log file,....?

Comment: the error is returned by the browser when requesting `wss://websocket.example.com:8443/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your certificate isn't trusted by the browser, which is not allowing you to access the WebSocket. You need to either add the CA to you computer's/browser's trust store or get a trusted cert. If you do want a trusted cert you could use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) or you could pay for a SSL cert from any number of companies that sell such things.

To add to the trust store of your machine try these links (the basic premise of which is to find where the browser stores the CA/Cert information and manually add yours):

- [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)
- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1059377

With the new information you provided you may need to fix your nginx conf, add the web socket location as a passthrough in the nginx conf.

```
location /websocket/ {

proxy_pass ​http://backend_host;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_read_timeout 86400;
```

}

Comment: I have now switched to a trusted cert and it still doesn't work